# Unable to create directory, /usr/local/cuda/include for tensorflow GPU Enabled

Tags: directory, cuda

I am trying to install GPU enabled tensor flow on Ubuntu 14.04. One of the commands is `sudo cp cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v4.0-prod.tgz/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include` and I get the error message `cp: failed to access ‘/usr/local/cuda/include’: Not a directory`. But I cannot access `/usr/local/cuda/` to create the `/include/` folder but I know cuda exists, see below, I just used the ls command.

```
john@john-desktop:/usr/local$ ls
bin  cuda  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
john@john-desktop:/usr/local$ cd cuda
bash: cd: cuda: Not a directory
john@john-desktop:/usr/local$ cd /usr/local/cuda
bash: cd: /usr/local/cuda: Not a directory
```

How do I create the `/usr/local/cuda/include/` folder so I can install Cudnn to that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/cuda/include/
```

But that command should be part of the installation process. Either done automatically or part of the commands you need to type manually.

Problem you probably face: the "cuda" in "/usr/local/" is a FILE and not a directory. If so do a ...

```
ls -l /usr/local/cuda
```

and confirm yourself it is a file. If you created it yourself or you know it is useless you can do a...

```
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda
```

to remove the file "cuda" and you can then create the directory.

Comment: that worked but I still can't get this installed. Is there a place I can just pay someone to install it on my computer for me? I have tried numerous times and I am losing my mind.

Comment: ehm. no, well... not from askubuntu and it would be VERY UNWISE to do so since you'd be handing over total access to your system.  If I was you I would make a new question. Show where you got the installer from. Show what is asked to install it. And ask about the problem you then face.  Someone (if not me :P ) would be happy to help.

Comment: zif this is the one: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Install-Caffe-on-EC2-from-scratch-(Ubuntu,-CUDA-7,-cuDNN)  this is probaly where you went wrong sudo ./cuda-linux64-rel-7.0.28-19326674.run ;-)

Comment: I downloaded the .Deb and saved it so I installed it with the GUI. How can I change the path information?